# Error: no se puede asignar un valor de tipo "char *" a una entidad de tipo "char" en una pila

Tags: c++, pilas

Estoy intentando hacer un pequeño ejercicio usando pilas en el que introduzca nombres y luego los imprima. Como es la primera vez que hago esto me basé en el código del video de *Programación ATS* y por alguna razón en la **línea 48** me sale este error:

> **no se puede asignar un valor de tipo "char *" a una entidad de tipo "char"** .

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct Nodo {
    char nombre[10];
    Nodo *siguiente;
};

void agregar (Nodo *&pila, char name);
void sacar(Nodo *&pila, char &name);

int main() {
    Nodo *pila = NULL;
    char nombre[10];
    char resp;

    do {
        cout << "\nDigite un nombre: ";
        cin >> nombre;
        agregar(pila, *nombre);

        cout << "\nDesea agregar otro nombre ? Introduzca S para si o N para no: ";
        cin >> resp;

    }while((resp ='S')||(resp = 's'));

    while(pila!= NULL){
        sacar(pila, *nombre);
    }
}

void agregar (Nodo *&pila, char name){
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
    *nuevo_nodo->nombre = name;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = pila;
    pila = nuevo_nodo;

    cout << "\tElementos " << name << " agregados a PILA correctamebte" << endl;
}

void sacar(Nodo *&pila, char &name){
    Nodo *aux = pila;
    name = aux->nombre;
    pila = aux->siguiente;
    delete aux;
}
```

Comment: Los nodos tienen el campo nombre de tipo char* (una cadena C), pero están declarados como char en las funciones: `void agregar (Nodo *&pila, char name);`. De todas formas está mal usado. Intentás asignar como `name = aux->nombre;`. Eso solo asigna el puntero. Cada nodo tiene su búffer de tamaño 10, así que deberías copiar byte a byte en lugar de asignar. Si titulas con una duda puntual sobre cómo hacerlo en lugar de titular con el error, te puedo ayudar a mejorarlo.

Answer (score 1):

> por alguna razón en la **línea 48** me sale este error

Por favor, observa que en tu publicación no se muestran los números de línea. Por suerte 48 no es un número muy grande para contar líneas, por desgracia me da muchísima pereza contar así que no se dónde está la línea 48.

Pero no necesito buscar la línea 48 para ver el fallo, pues es bastante obvio:

```
struct Nodo {
    char nombre[10]; // el tipo de 'nombre' es 'char[10]'
    Nodo *siguiente;
};

void agregar (Nodo *&pila, char name){
...
    *nuevo_nodo->nombre = name;
//               ~~2~~~   ~~1~ <--- Asigna 1 'char' a 2 'char[10]'
...
}
```

Las formaciones<sup>1</sup> en C++ tienen como tipo `tipo[tamaño]` y son implícitamente convertibles<sup>2</sup> a `tipo *`. En tu caso `char[10]` se convierte a `char *` porque una formación no puede estar a la izquierda de una asignación (`=`) pero (normalmente) un puntero si puede, una vez convertida la formación a puntero se intenta asignar a la variable a su derecha y falla al ser incompatibles los tipos `char *` y `char`.

Lo que en realidad querías hacer es esto:

```
struct Nodo {
    std::string nombre;
    Nodo *siguiente;
};

void agregar (Nodo *&pila, const std::string &name);
void sacar(Nodo *&pila, std::string &name);
```

Usando cadenas (`std::string`) las operaciones de asignación de valores están definidas.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

<sup>2</sup>Implícitamente convertible significa que el programador no debe hacer nada para que esta conversión suceda.